# PrintWriter is not printing anything

Tags: java

I'm trying to read from a text file containing column names of a table and write getter and setter methods into a java file using `java.io.PrintWriter`. Program is compiling and running successfully but PrintWriter is not printing anything. So a blank `.java` file is created.

```
package model;

import java.io.*;  
import java.util.*;

public class FileReadWrite {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/491003/Documents/FileReadWrite/TAB1F_Input.txt");
            File file1 = new File("C:/Users/491003/Desktop/Output.java");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file1);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            String st;  
            String regex = "_";

            pw.write("package Desktop;\n\npublic class Output{\n\n");  

            while (sc.hasNext()) { 
                st = sc.next();
                if (st.contains("_")) {
                    st = st.replaceAll(regex,"");
                    st = st.toLowerCase();
                    pw.write("public String "+st+";\n");
                    pw.write("public String get"+st+"(){");
                    pw.write("return "+st+";}\n");
                    pw.write
                      "public void set" + st
                      + "(String new" + st
                      + "){" + st
                      + "=new" + st
                      +";}\n"
                    );
                }
                //System.out.println(sc.next()+" ");
            }
            pw.write("\n}");               

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: after printing please close/flush printwriter.

Comment: Thanks Zia. It worked.